# How to manually calculate odds ratio for continuous variables?

Tags: odds-ratio, mathematical-statistics, calculus

In school, long before learning about logistic models, I've been taught how to calculate odds ratios by hand.

Formula was based on a contingency table, just like this:
[image: contingency table and oddsratio formula]

This is very easy to understand for categorical variables (even with 3+ levels by one-hot encoding), but for a continuous variable a logistic model would give me an OR "for a predictor increase of 1".

What would be the odds ratio calculation for such a continuous variable ?

**EDIT:** this is a question of curiosity, aiming at better understanding the logic behind models I fit daily

Comment: Is there a reason you'd rather not just fit the model and take the antilog of the estimate?

Comment: this question is about understanding, not performing. I think knowing how to calculate something is often a very good way to understand it.

Comment: [This](http://vassarstats.net/logreg1.html) explains the basic idea for a discrete independent variable.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight so the answer is that unlike for categorical variables, you cannot really calculate such an odds ratio without fitting a logistic regression ?

Comment: If you're talking about something as simple as ad/bc, then you're correct that there is no such shortcut.

Comment: Well this is the answer to my question, thanks. If you mind to post it I'll accept it.